# can´t understand fetchRequest.predicate

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, nspredicate

I´ve a quite "simple" predicate for a NSFetchRequest:

```
guard let kategorie = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? Kategorien else {
            return
}
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Details")
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "kategorie == %i", kategorie.katid!)
do {
    let results = try self.managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [Details]
...
```

The content of the sqllite-"table" is
[image]

the content of the variables are

[image]

So from

```
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "kategorie == %i", kategorie.katid!)
```

i get the Predicate

> kategorie == 18

while

> kategorie.katid is 1

I can´t understand it :-(

Any help???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`katid` is an (optional) `NSNumber`, and what happens in your case
is that the (lower 32-bit of the) *address* of the object is taken as an integer.

The correct format
specifier is `%@` (for instances of `NSObject` subclasses):

```
 NSPredicate(format: "kategorie == %@", kategorie.katid!)
```

Alternatively, convert the object to an integer:

```
NSPredicate(format: "kategorie == %d", kategorie.katid!.intValue)
```

Of course, forced unwrapping should be avoided, e.g.

```
NSPredicate(format: "kategorie == %d", kategorie.katid?.intValue ?? 0)
```

Using string interpolation in the format string (as suggested by
@Gargoyle) is another solution in this special case of numbers, 
but not generally: If you interpolate a *string* then any percent
character will be interpreted as a format specifier and that leads
to unexpected output or crashes. Also single or double quotes will
lead to problems because these have a special meaning in predicate
format strings.

Comment: @ Martin R: Thank u for the explanation

Comment: Good comment about the quotes and percents.  That's never come up for me but it's a definite concern to make people aware of!

Answer (score 3):

That's really strange, but you can just do:

```
NSPredicate(format: "kategorie = \(kategorie.katid!)")
```

And then you don't need to worry about whether you need a %i, or a %ld, or a %@, etc...